# How does TCP connection terminate if one of the machine dies?

Tags: networking, tcp

If a TCP connection is established between two hosts (A & B), and lets say host A has sent 5 octets to host B, and then the host B crashes (due to unknown reason). 
The host A will wait for acknowledgments, but on not getting them, will resend octets and also reduce the sender window size.
This will repeat couple times till the window size shrinks to zero because of packet loss. My question is, what will happen next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, TCP eventually times out waiting for the ack's and return an error to the application. The application have to read/recv from the TCP socket to learn about that error,  a subsequent write/send call will fail as well. Up till the point that TCP determined that the connection is gone, write/send calls will not fail, they'll succeed as seen from the application or block if the socket buffer is full.

In the case your host B vanishes after it has sent its ACKs, host A will not learn about that until it sends something to B, which will eventually also time out, or result in an ICMP error. (Typically the first write/send call will not fail as TCP will not fail the connection immediately, and keep in mind that write/send calls does not wait for ACKs until they complete).

Note also that retransmission does not reduce the window size.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)

now a very simple answer to your question in my view is, The connection will be timed out and will be closed. another possibility that exists is that some ICMP error might be generated due to due un-responsive machine.

Also, if the crashed machine is online again, then the procedure described in the link i just pasted above will be observed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the OS implementation.  In short it  will wait for ACK and resend packets until it times out. Then your connection will be torn down.  To see exactly what happens in Linux look [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.7/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c#L320)  other OSes follow similar algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, A FIN will be generated (by the surviving node) and connection will eventually migrate to CLOSED state. If you keep grep-ing for netstat output on the destination ip address, you will watch the migration from ESTABLISHED state to TIMED_WAIT and then finally disappear.

In your case, this will happen since TCP keeps a timer to get the ACK for the packet it has sent. This timer is not long enough so detection will happen pretty quickly.

However, if the machine B dies after A gets ACK and after that A doesn't send anything, then the above timer can't detect the same event, however another timer (calls idle timeout) will detect that condition and connection will close then. This timeout period is high by default. But normally this is not the case, machine A will try to send stuff in between and will detect the error condition in send path.

In short, TCP is smart enough to close the connection by itself (and let application know about it) except for one case (Idle timeout: which by default is very high).

cforfun

Comment: How can the dying machine generate a FIN if it dies?

Comment: @EJP: a TCP FIN can be generated by both ends: Error handling in surviving side can do an active close in its implementation and you may watch FIN_WAIT_1 state in netstat output for this connection in surviving node.

Comment: But what if it dies before generating the FIN?

Comment: @EJP: but node1 is the surviving node which can generate the FIN! take this case: there is a TCP connection between node1 and node2 node2 dies, but node1 gets an error timeout due to one of its timeout mechanism: all I am saying that node1's error handling will transition the state to FIN_WAIT_1 and eventually close the connection: if you trap all the connection states of error handling in lowest level connection code in kernel, you can watch this state transition happing.

Comment: The surviving node won't generate a FIN unless the application closes the socket or shuts it down. It will not generate a FIN for a broken or reset connection. It will eventually generate an internal reset, if there was data pending to be sent.

Comment: @EJP: application in this case will get a send error, and most of the socket apps upon getting send error will close/shutdown the connection, which will try to send FIN, put the connection state in FIN_WAIT-1, which will not get a FIN-ACK in this case and will eventually timeout and eventually it will be closed. There are many other ways it can be cleaned up, but don't you think this is a possible way? If you agree please give back my hard earned two points :-) cheers, cforfun :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8287/discussion-between-cforfun-and-ejp)

Comment: The *application*, not the *node*, will generate a FIN *if it was sending* and *if it gets a send error* and *if it reacts to the send error by closing the socket.* If the application was reading without a timeout it will sit there forever and the 'surviving node' will never generate a FIN.

Comment: @EJP: right, you can view both ways: application running on the

Comment: @EJP: right, looks like you have answered your own question. now let's go back to your original question for which you did a "-1" on my answer. you said: "How can the dying machine generate a FIN if it dies?" you answered: "application [i added: running on surviving node] can generate the FIN" and I said earlier: a FIN will be generated (never said FIN will be generated by the dying machine): I hope this clarifies that gap we had. I rest my case!

Comment: A FIN *may* be generated. Have a look at all the 'if's in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

In normal cases, each side terminating its end of the connectivity by sending a special message with a FIN(finish) bit set.
The device receiving this FIN responds with an acknowledgement to the FIN to indicate that it has been received.
The connection as a whole is not considered terminated until both the devices complete the shut down procedure by sending an FIN and receiving an acknowledgement.